# The 'launchimage' for my trigger.io app is too small on a Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, galaxy, trigger.io

I've set up a launchimage for the Android app I'm developing on a brand new Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

```
"launchimage": {
            "android": "images/splash.png",
            "android-landscape": "images/splash.png"
        },
```

When I launch the app, the image shows.

But it doesn't fill the screen like it should.

The image is 720x1280, which is the native resolution of the Galaxy Nexus.

How can I display a launchimage that is the proper full size?

Comment: Yes it is.  Here is my related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564509/trigger-io-programmatically-set-orientation

Comment: @KrisKrause Sorry, how does that relate to my question? "Yes it is" – yes what is? Thanks for the help, just wanting to properly understand your suggestion :)

Comment: what orientation are you launching the app in, and what orientation is your launchimage? If you use the same launchimage for both portrait and landscape orientations, we will have to scale it down for one of them...

Comment: @JamesBrady - I am launching in portrait.  And it looks like a teeny tiny little logo against a massive black background.

Comment: @KrisKrause we only scale the logo down proportionally to fit on the screen - is it big enough in the first place? Point taken on programmatic orientation fixing, however: we'll do that too.

Comment: @JamesBrady I'm having the same issue on the device mentioned above (Galaxy Nexus) when starting in portrait mode. My launch image is 600px wide, so it should nearly fill the whole width of the screen, but in reality it takes about one third of it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this seems to be the down-scaling of images due to the devices pixel ratio / pixel density.

Example: The Samsung Galaxy Nexus has a pixel ratio of 2 ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung)). If you want to have a full width launch image in landscape mode (1280 x 720 px), you'd need an image with at least 1280x2 = **2560 pixel in width**. For full width in portrait mode you need at least **720x2 = 1440 pixel in width**.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with resource loading on high pixel density screens - it's fixed in v1.4.24 of the Trigger.io platform.

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-24

Answer (score -1):

The Info you provided is very less, but as far as i am understanding,

if you are setting the image in image view
you should have you Xml for launch image as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/launchimage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:src="@drawable/launchimage"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>

<LinearLayout/>

or alertnativiely
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/launchimage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout/>
```

LinearLayout is not compulsory you can choose layout of your choice